# AT commands with Telnet / Socket in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, telnet, at-command

I have a device that i want to send AT commands i am able to connect to the device with telnet or with a socket.

My issue is that i am unable to send the AT command or know how to receive it, i have found a few articles about this subject but they all talk about serial connection.

My question is what would be the proper way to send an AT commands if i am connected to the terminal by Telnet or a Socket and to receive the response

i have tried both socket.send("AT\n") and telnet.write(b"AT")

"AT" should just respond with "OK" status

Comment: How do you know you're connected? What happens when you do `socket.send("AT\n")`

Comment: i am getting the length of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct AT command handling is as follows:

You need to send the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36487352/23118), then **read and parse** ([framing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977157/23118)) AT command responses until you receive a Final result code.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688517/23118) (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36899432/23118), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816861/23118) or some of my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A23118%20[at-command]%20is%3Aanswer)) for details on how the logic for reading and parsing should be.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you tried this, but after [don't forget the .encode() and .decode() for send and recv]

```
s=socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))
s.send("AT\n".encode())
```

You have to use

```
data=s.recv(1024).decode()
print(data)
```

To receive information. Then, you close the socket with

```
s.close()
```

Hope that helped!