# Parsing the payload of the AT commands from the full response string

Tags: c, string, at-command, string-parsing

I want to parse the actual payload from the output of AT commands.

For instance: in the example below, I'd want to read only `"2021/11/16,11:12:14-32,0"`

```
AT+QLTS=1                          // command
+QLTS: "2021/11/16,11:12:14-32,0"  // response

OK
```

In the following case, I'd need to only read `12345678`.

```
AT+CIMI     // command
12345678   // example response
```

So the point is: not all commands have the same format for the output. We can assume the response is stored in a string array.

I have `GetAtCmdRsp()` already implemented which stores the response in a char array.

```c
void GetPayload()
{
  char rsp[100] = {0};
  GetAtCmdRsp("AT+QLTS=1", rsp);
  // rsp now contains +QLTS: "2021/11/16,11:12:14-32,0"
  // now, I need to parse "2021/11/16,11:12:14-32,0" out of the response
  
  memset(rsp, 0, sizeof(rsp));

  GetAtCmdRsp("AT+CIMI", rsp);
  // rsp now contains 12345678   
  // no need to do additional parsing since the output already contains the value I need
}
```

I was thinking of doing `char *start = strstr(rsp, ":") + 1;` to get the start of the payload but some responses may only contain the payload as it's the case with `AT+CIMI`

Perhaps could regex be a good idea to determine the pattern `+<COMMAND>:` in a string?

Comment: I would suggest abstracting `GetAtCmdRsp` further to be command specific. Or at least pass in an abstract enum/define instead of a fixed string and let the implementation generate the string and the correct response parsing specific to each command.

Comment: If you don't want to add command awareness to your implementation then an alternative would be to use heuristics - e.g. if response contains `:` then parse accordingly else return whole string. But that may be less robust and end up having to handle many different cases anyway.

Comment: Fiddling with the standard library to do, often complex, state machines is a headache, (with backtracking, I understand?) Use [re2c](https://re2c.org/manual/manual_c.html), '@' parser.

Comment: @kaylum I can't just parse based on `:` alone though as mentioned. The payload could also contain `:`

Comment: Yes that's why I said "end up having to handle many different cases anyway". The heurstic would need to take care of all the different cases. That was only provided as a second alternative - my first suggestion would be the preferred one IMHO.

Comment: `GetAtCmdRsp(AT_CMD_QLTS, rsp); GetAtCmdRsp(AT_CMD_CIMI, rsp);` for example where the `AT_CMD` values are `enum`s or `#define`s

Answer (score 1):

In order to parse AT command responses a good starting point is **understanding all the possible formats they can have**.
 So, rather than implementing a command specific routine, I would discriminate commands by *"type of response"*:

1. Commands with **no payload** in their answers, for example

   ```
    AT
    OK
   ```
2. Commands with **no header** in their answers, such as

   ```
    AT+CIMI
    12345678

    OK
   ```
3. Commands with a single **header** in their answers

   ```
    AT+QLTS=1
    +QLTS: "2021/11/16,11:12:14-32,0"

    OK
   ```
4. Command with multi-line responses.
   Every line could of *"single header"* type, like in `+CGDCONT`:

   ```
   AT+CDGCONT?
   +CGDCONT: 1,"IP","epc.tmobile.com","0.0.0.0",0,0
   +CGDCONT: 2,"IP","isp.cingular","0.0.0.0",0,0
   +CGDCONT: 3,"IP","","0.0.0.0",0,0

   OK
   ```

   Or we could even have **mixed** types, like in `+CGML`:

   ```
    AT+CMGL="ALL"

    +CMGL: 1,"REC READ","+XXXXXXXXXX","","21/11/25,10:20:00+00"
    Good morning! How are you?

    +CMGL: 2,"REC READ","+XXXXXXXXXX","","21/11/25,10:33:33+00"
    I'll come a little late. See you. Bruce Wayne

    OK
   ```

   (please note how it could have also *"empty"* lines, that is `\r\n`).

At the moment I cannot think about any other scenario.
In this way you'll be able to define an enum like

```
typedef enum
{
    AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE,
    AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_NO_HEADER,
    AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_SINGLE_HEADER,
    AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_MULTILINE,
    AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_MAX
}
```

and pass it to your `GetAtCmdRsp( )` function in order to parser the response accordingly. If implement the differentiation in that function, or after it (or in an external function is your choice.

---

### A solution without *explicit* categorization

Once you have clear all the scenarios that might ever occur, you can think about a general algorithm working for all of them:

1. Get the full response `resp` after the command echo and before the closing `OK` or `ERROR`. **Make sure that the trailing `\r\n\r\nOK` is removed** (or `\r\nERROR`. Or `\r\nNO CARRIER`. Or whatever the terminating message of the response might be).
   Make also sure to remove the command echo
2. If `strlen( resp ) == 0` we belong to the `NO_RESPONSE` category, and the job is done
3. If the response contains `\r\n`s in it, we have a `MULTILINE` answer. So, tokenize it and place every line into an array element `resp_arr[i]`. Make sure to remove trailing `\r\n`
4. **For every line in the response** (for every `resp_arr[i]` element), search for `<CMD> :` pattern (**not only `:`**, that might be contained in the payload as well!). Something like that:

   ```
    size_t len = strlen( resp_cur_line );
    char *payload;

    if( strstr( "+YOURCMD: ", resp_cur_line) == NULL )
    {
        // We are in "NO_HEADER" case
        payload = resp_cur_line;
    }
    else
    {
        // We are in "HEADER" case
        payload = resp_cur_line + strlen( "+YOURCMD: " );
    }
   ```

   Now `payload` pointer points to the actual payload.

   Please note how, in case of `MULTILINE` answer, after splitting the lines into array elements every loop will handle correctly also the mixed scenarios like the one in `+CMGL`, as you'll be able to distinguish the lines containing the header from those containing data (and from the empty lines, of course). For a deeper analysis about `+CMGL` response parsing have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873777/11336762).

Comment: Regarding `At the moment I cannot think about any other scenario`-  there is one more: multiple responses that each span multiple lines, for instance `+CMGL: <index>,<stat>,<oa/da>,[<alpha>],[<scts>][,<tooa/toda>,<length>]<CR><LF><data>[<CR><LF>`. As such the names `AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_HEADER` and `AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_MULTILINE` probably would be better as `AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_HEADER_SINGLE` and `AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_HEADER_MULTIPLE` with additional `AT_RESPONSE_TYPE_HEADER_MULTIPLE_MULTILINE` for the CMGL use case.

Comment: Although it is possible to use less granular division, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873777/23118) for an example where I just use CMGL_NONE, CMGL_PREFIX and CMGL_DATA (for `AT+CMGL` specifically though).

Comment: @hlovdal thanks for your suggestion. I actually forgot `+CMGL` :). I renamed "HEADER" case to "SINGLE_HEADER", like you suggested, but I kept "MULTILINE" as a single scenario. In fact, with the purpose of removing the header, "multiline mixed case" is fortunately covered by my pseudo-code, as every line will be parsed accordingly. ;) The answer you linked is more specific for `+CMGL` and I linked it.

Comment: @hlovdal BTW: all our wise suggestions will work only until some annoying guy will send SMSs starting with `+CMGL: `. :)