# Sending multiple SMS via 3G modem (AT command)

Tags: c#, serial-port, sms, at-command, modem

I would like to send multiple SMS via 3G modem to about ~ 500 GSM numbers/users...

Whereafter 20-30 SMS, it does not return any value (void) from serial port and modem is locking up... When I disconnect USB modem and connect again, the problem is solving temporarily.

How can I solve this problem permanently?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + "phonenumber" + "\"\r\n");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                serialPort.Write("Hi:"+i.ToString() + "\x1A");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                string t = serialPort.ReadExisting();

                if(t.Length>0)
                    ....
                else
                    .....
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote the following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506759/unable-in-reading-sms-from-3g-usb-dongle#comment72523692_42506759), and it equally applies to your question as well:

> `Is this practice causes any issue?` This is the **single worst** beginner
>   mistake you can do with regards to AT command handling. You should
>   *never, never, never, ever* use Thread.Sleep or anything similar to [wait for response from a modem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688517/23118). It's as useful as kicking dogs that
>   stand in your way in order to get them to move. Yes you might be lucky
>   and have it actually work sometimes, but at some point you will be
>   sorry for taking that approach...

For that question it was not clear what the problem is, but in your case I think it is the core problem. You cannot just throw a bunch of AT command at the modem and then later try to catch up with ReadExisting. That will never work reliably.

You must **read and parse** everything received from the modem in a proper fashion (see my answer linked above).