# Unable in reading SMS from 3g USB dongle

Tags: c#, at-command

I'm building a windows service to read `SMS` from `3G dongle` storage set as SIM card using AT commands. It's working good but some times it fails and response shows `+CPMS: 0,0,0,0,0,0` .

## Code

```
        gsmPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1"); //Set mode to Text(1) or PDU(0)
        gsmPort.WriteLine("AT+CPMS=\"SM\""); //Set storage to SIM(SM), MODEM(ME), BOTH(MT)
        gsmPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\""); //What catagory to read ALL, REC READ, or REC UNREAD

        response = gsmPort.ReadExisting();
```

When i move dongle into another port it starts working. I've tride it on multiple systems with different dongle but the result is always same. I've also changed my SIM card but no effect. Can any one have any idea why after some time SIM storage shows 0/0.

Comment: Just for my knowledge why we need Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: Using `Thread.Sleep` is not the best way to write state machines in C# as @Anil wrote. Also, don't these other commands also return status (`"OK"` or something)?

Comment: I'm using `Thread.Sleep` here to provide some time in registering commands. Is this practice causes any issue? Also above commands return response containing received message details and storage details.

Comment: What is the brand and model of the dongle?

Comment: Is the `gmPort.WriteLine` an async command, that is why you are using `Thread.Sleep`? If so, I believe that you should try to use the `await` keyword or try to implement a callback to know when the data has finished writing.

Comment: `Is this practice causes any issue?` This is the **single worst** beginner mistake you can do with regards to AT command handling. You should *never, never, never, ever* use Thread.Sleep or anything similar to [wait for response from a modem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31688517/23118). It's as useful as kicking dogs that stand in your way in order to get them to move. Yes you might be lucky and have it actually work sometimes, but at some point you will be sorry for taking that approach...

Comment: Gotten around to solve this?