# Send SMS from Java form using JSSC and Android phone

Tags: java, at-command

I need your help in this topic:

I want to send text messages from a phone that is connected with USB to a laptop and sending the text should be write from a Java form. I tried to do some code using JSSC library, but something it doesn't work because the SMS is not sent. Connection is good, communication is good too, but the text message is not sent. Can either of you help me with this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3");
    char enter = 13;
    char control_z=26;
    char comilla = 34;
    try {
        System.out.println("Port open: " + port.openPort());
        System.out.println("Params setted: " + port.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));     

        System.out.println("Set to SMS: " + port.writeBytes(("AT+CMGF=1"+enter).getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Set the destinatar: " + port.writeBytes(("AT+CMGS"+comilla+"+phone_number"+comilla+enter).getBytes()));
        System.out.println("Set the text: " + port.writeBytes(("text"+control_z).getBytes()));

        System.out.println("Port closed: " + port.closePort());
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your mistake? Could you attach the error?

Comment: Actually everything looks like it's going good, but it isn't. The output is showing (with a good phone number :) ):
run:
Port open: true
Params setted: true
Set to SMS: true
Set the destinatar: true
Set the text: true
Port closed: true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: I'm using windows 64bit and I can't use the comm library ... :(

Comment: How do you connect android phone to com port to PC

Answer (score 0):

You are aborting the commands you are issuing. You should be **reading** and **parsing** the responses you get back from the modem. See the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118), and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266839/23118) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688517/23118) answer.